# Tensor product of $\partial_i$ and $dx^j$

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, tensors

In general the tensor product is not commutative. But I have a doubt:

in defining the absolute derivative (or covariant derivative) of a vector field $X$, as $\nabla X\in \cal{T_{1}^{1}(\cal{M})}$ (tensor field of type $(1,1)$) I have read that it is defined by:
$$\nabla X=\xi_{;j}^{i}dx^j\otimes \partial_i$$ with $X=\xi^i\partial_i$.

But in defining  a vector field of type $(1,1)$ in coordinates I know that it can be written as
$$t=t_i^j\partial_i\otimes dx^j$$
So it seems that $\partial_i$ and $dx^j$ are shifted in the order in defining $\nabla X$ with respect to the general definition of a tensor field of type $(1,1)$.

How it is possible? Maybe it is true that $\partial_i\otimes dx^j=dx^j\otimes \partial_i$?

Comment: it depends on which convention the author uses. they are not equal but are isomorph. just know that where the input vector (that, that (1,1)-tensor want to eat) must effect. the first place or in second place? some authors use $\nabla T(X,Y)=(\nabla_X T)Y$ while others  $\nabla T(X,Y)=(\nabla_Y T)X$.

Comment: Some others are a bit more precautious and write it $\nabla T(X;Y,Z)$ for $(\nabla_XT)(Y,Z)$, showing that $X$ is separated from $Y$ and $Z$. I find it very useful.

Comment: My book use the notation $\nabla X(Y, \omega)$...so what it the correct order for $\partial_i$ and $dx^j$?

Comment: In my own work, I rarely, if ever, use the term "$(p,q)$-tensor". Each tensor should be defined explicitly, and the notation established at the same time. It is of course good to be consistent about one's notation, but often different notation is appropriate in different contexts. For example, a Riemannian metric and an exterior $2$-form are both $(0,2)$-tensors. However, they are treated and written quite differently. With a $(1,1)$-tensor, whether order matters depends on, among other things, whether you will be using a metric to raise or lower indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your conventions. Some books define a $(1,1)$ tensor to be a section of $T^{*}M \otimes TM$ (the cotangent bundle appears first) while others define a $(1,1)$ tensor to be a section of $TM \otimes T^{*}M$ (the tangent bundle appears first). The bundles are of course isomorphic but still one makes a certain choice.

Let's say your convention is $TM \otimes T^{*}M$. Then the expression $dx^i \otimes \partial_j$ is not a "legal" $(1,1)$ tensor since it is not a section of $TM \otimes T^{*}M$. Once a choice is made, one uses certain isomorphisms to identify $(1,1)$-tensors with bilinear or linear maps. This choice is also somewhat arbitrary but most people try to be consistent. In the case of $TM \otimes T^{*}M$, one can identify sections of this bundle with smoothly varying bilinear maps $T_p^{*}M \times T_pM \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by declaring that
$$ (\alpha \otimes X)(Y, \omega) = \alpha(Y) \cdot \omega(X) $$
(and extending linearly). Note that the first argument $Y$ is a vector field and it "acts" on the first factor $\alpha$ (which is a one-form) and similarly the second argument $\omega$ is a one-form and it acts on the second factor $X$ (which is a vector field). One could do it the other way around but this is not common.

So in your case, the notation $(\nabla X)(Y,\omega)$ suggests that $(1,1)$-tensors are considered as sections of $T^{*}M \otimes TM$ and the formula $\nabla X = \xi^i_{;j} dx^j \otimes \partial_i$ is consistent with this guess.

Answer (score 1):

Some authors define a tensor of type $(1,1)$ to be, in local coordinates:
$$ \label{1}
T = \sum_{i,j} T^i_j \partial_i \otimes \mathrm{d}x^j, \tag{1}
$$
while others prefer to define it the other way
$$ \label{2}
T = \sum_{i,j} T^i_j \mathrm{d}x^j\otimes \partial_i \tag{2}
$$
I personally prefer \eqref{2} because if given a vector field $X$, one can feel that in the writing $\left(\mathrm{d}x^j\otimes \partial_i\right)(X)$, it becomes $\mathrm{d}x^j(X) \partial_i$ and the left part is a coefficient $\times $ the vector field $\partial_i$. In this case, a $(1,1)$-tensor is a section of $T^*M\otimes TM$.

In case \eqref{1}, $(1,1)$-tensors are sections of $TM\otimes T^*M$. This looks a bit unnatural to me as I learned during my studies that we have a natural isomorphism $\mathrm{End}(E) \simeq E^*\otimes E$ (coefficient $\times$ vector), not the other way. Again, this is a personal taste.

One a choice is made, you have to try being consistent. Your first equation $\nabla X = \xi^i_j \mathrm{d}x^j \otimes \partial_i$ is suggesting that the convention is \eqref{2}.

**Edit** I did not notice that there was another answer (I took my time writing this up), and it seems we are basically saying the same thing. The other answer is a bit more accurate as it explains how to understand the notation $\alpha \otimes X \left(Y,\omega \right)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! To be honest I have accepted the other answer for the reason why it is previous of yours. Anyway also your answer it is very useful for me!

Comment: @cely This is fair enough. I am not looking for score, do not worry about that, I'm glad I helped you